# std::strcpy and std::strcat with a std::string argument

Tags: c++

[image]

This is from C++ Primer 5th edition. What do they mean by "the size of `largeStr`". `largeStr` is an instance of `std::string` so they have dynamic sizes?

Also I don't think the code compiles:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    std::string s("test");
    const char ca1[] = "apple";
    std::strcpy(s, ca1);
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: @PeteBecker The book often uses variable definitions from previous sections of code

Comment: @PeteBecker Screenshots of code are bad, but this is a passage from a typeset book. It's fine.

Comment: `strcpy` and `strcat` do not take `std::string`, so it's clear that the authors of the book omitted a second definition of `char largeString[N]` in the second snippet of code, since they are clearly trying to make a comparison between C++ and C, highlighting how concatenating strings differs between the two languages.

Comment: @JohnKugelman -- when I wrote my comment there was no definition of `largeStr`. The question has been edited, without mentioning that this problem was fixed.

Comment: The book does say "We must pass an array to hold the resulting string"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcpy` and `strcat` only operate on C strings. The passage is confusing because it describes but does not explicitly show a manually-sized C string. In order for the second snippet to compile, `largeStr` must be a different variable from the one in the first snippet:

```
char largeStr[100];

// disastrous if we miscalculated the size of largeStr
strcpy(largeStr, ca1);        // copies ca1 into largeStr
strcat(largeStr, " ");        // adds a space at the end of largeStr
strcat(largeStr, ca2);        // concatenates ca2 onto largeStr
```

As described in the second paragraph, `largeStr` here is an array. Arrays have fixed sizes decided at compile time, so we're forced to pick some arbitrary size like `100` that we expect to be large enough to hold the result. However, this approach is "fraught with potential for serious error" because `strcpy` and `strcat` don't *enforce* the size limit of `100`.

> Also I don't think the code compiles...

As above, change `s` to an array and it will compile.

```
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char s[100] = "test";
    const char ca1[] = "apple";
    std::strcpy(s, ca1);
}
```

Notice that I didn't write `char s[] = "test";`. It's important to reserve extra space for `"apple"` since it's longer than `"test"`.

Comment: Thanks. I was sure 99.999% it was a mistake. But since they used previous definitions from past pages, it felt very weird.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the

```
char largeStr[100];
```

or similar the book doesn't mention.

What you should do is forget about strcpy and strcat and C-style strings real quick. Just remember how to make c++ `std::string` out of them and never look back.